# Vapor error H13 on Heroku

Tags: swift, heroku, vapor

My program seems to work fine on Heroku, but after reloading the page 3-4 times, it crashes, and I get the error `H13: Connection closed without response`.
However, it works perfectly fine and without any error when I run it on my computer.

Here is my code:

```
#if os(Linux)
  import Glibc
#else
  import Darwin
#endif
import Vapor

let arrayA: [String] = ["some strings here"]

let arrayB: [String] = ["more strings there"]

let arrayC: [String] = ["and some more here"]

func buildName (from arrayA: [String], and arrayB: [String], and arrayC: [String]) -> String {
  #if os(Linux)
    let a: Int = Int(random() % (arrayA.count + 1))
    let b: Int = Int(random() % (arrayB.count + 1))
    let c: Int = Int(random() % (arrayC.count + 1))
  #else
    let a: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayA.count)))
    let b: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayB.count)))
    let c: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayC.count)))
  #endif

  return (arrayA[a] + " " + arrayB[b] + " " + arrayC[c])
}

let defaultHead: String = "<head><meta charset='utf-8'></head>"

//create Droplet object
let drop = Droplet()

// REGISTER Routes and handlers
drop.get { req in
  return buildName(from: arrayA, and: arrayB, and: arrayC)
}

// Start the server
drop.run()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this error cannot come from this code. Check Heroku settings instead.

Comment: H13 - Connection closed without response
This error is thrown when a process in your web dyno accepts a connection, but then closes the socket without writing anything to it. I'm not sure why that would happen in this instance, but clearly somewhere there was an unwritten socket connection after reloads.

Comment: @EricAya Which settings should I check specifically? I haven't really changed any of them (apart from adding the `https://github.com/kylef/heroku-buildpack-swift.git` backpack).

Comment: No idea, I just know that this code you're showing is unlikely to be the source of your issue. As Ryan hints, this is very probably an issue on Heroku's side instead.

Comment: So there's nothing I can't do? Should I contact Heroku?

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/689

Comment: I contacted Heroku Support, but they can't support third party buildpacks. However, I managed to fix it just by moving the `buildName` function to its own struct and then calling it from an instance of that. No idea on why it works, but somehow it does.

Comment: @Walkersneps I left you a DM on the Vapor Slack channel with some help from a Vapor developer. Glad you got it fixed, but it'd be good to know why.

Answer (score 0):

`let a: Int = Int(random() % (arrayA.count + 1))`

this line generate a number may equal to ArrayA.count.
So, it may produce `fatal error: Index out of range`.

So, I think this is the mainly reason.

Answer (score 0):

arc4random_uniform does not work on linux. 
use this instead:

```
public static func randomInt(min: Int, max:Int) -> Int {
        #if os(Linux)
            return Glibc.random() % max
        #else
            return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
        #endif
    }
```